# Dropdownlist issue when clicking back on Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, web-parts, kentico

I have a webpart with 3 dropdownlists. The 2nd and 3rd ones are dependent on the 1rst one (the options will change depending on the option selected in the 1rst ddl). All 3 dropdownlists have disabled options (ie: "Please select a city") which are preselected.

Upon choosing all 3 ddls, the user can click a button and is redirected to another page. Currently, on Chrome, when I click Back, the first ddl retains the option I chose while the two others are blank. On other browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari), the options are back to the preselected disabled ones. I've tried removing cache, but it does not seem to work. It seems to be a browser specific issue.

I would like to know why this is happening on Chrome, and what would be the best way to fix it.

Comment: How are you populating the DropDownList items? Can we see the script you use to enable the 2nd and 3rd DropDownLists?  Do you have EnableViewState set to true?

Comment: Can you check JS console for any errors? Do you use any custom *OnChange client script*? Have you properly set *Depending fields* or *Depends on another field* properties? Which version (and hotfix) of Kentico do you use? Could you provide us export of the webpart?

Comment: I think it may be related to the fact that the DDLs are disabled. Try to remove the disabling functionality temporarily. Does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the webpart parameter `AJAX-->Use update panel` to true. If that's not it, turn off any Chrome extensions that might interfere, such as Adblocker.

Hope that helps!